# Getting my sidebar to transition between 2 states? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am trying to create a sidebar that transitions between 2 different states in flutter for a web application. At the moment it immediately moves between the 2 different positions and their is no transition. I suspect I haven't used the AnimatedPositioned Class correctly.

How am I able to get it to animate between the 2 different positions correctly?

```
class _SideNavigationBarState extends State<SideNavigationBar> with singleTickerProviderStateMixin<SideNavigationBar> {
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late StreamController<bool> isSideNavigationBarOpenedStreamController;
  late Stream<bool> isSideNavigationBarOpenedStream;
  late StreamSink<bool> isSideNavigationBarOpenedSink;
  final _animationDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 500);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: _animationDuration);
    isSideNavigationBarOpenedStreamController = PublishSubject<bool>();
    isSideNavigationBarOpenedStream = isSideNavigationBarOpenedStreamController.stream;
    isSideNavigationBarOpenedSink = isSideNavigationBarOpenedStreamController.sink;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    isSideNavigationBarOpenedStreamController.close();
    isSideNavigationBarOpenedSink.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void onIconPressed() {
    final animationStatus = _animationController.status;
    final isAnimationCompleted = animationStatus == AnimationStatus.completed;

    if (isAnimationCompleted) {
      isSideNavigationBarOpenedSink.add(false);
      _animationController.reverse();
    } else {
      isSideNavigationBarOpenedSink.add(true);
      _animationController.forward();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double size = 52;
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return StreamBuilder<bool>(
      initialData: false,
      stream: isSideNavigationBarOpenedStream,
      builder: (context, isSideNavigationBarOpenedAsync) {
        final icon = isSideNavigationBarOpenedAsync.data! ? Icons.arrow_back_ios 
            : Icons.arrow_forward_ios;
        return AnimatedPositioned(
          duration: _animationDuration,
          left: isSideNavigationBarOpenedAsync.data! ? 0 : -screenWidth,
          right: isSideNavigationBarOpenedAsync.data! ? 0 : screenWidth-45,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              isSideNavigationBarOpenedAsync.data!
                  ? Container(
                      width: 300,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      ):
                    
                  Container(
                      width: 45,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
            
              Align(
                  alignment: Alignment(0, -0.9),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        onIconPressed();
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        child: Material(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          child: InkWell(
                            child: Container(
                                width: size,
                                height: size,
                                child: Icon(icon,
                                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5)
                                )
                              ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                  ) 
                )
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you include more about `PublishSubject`

Comment: Exactly like a normal broadcast StreamController with one exception: this class is both a Stream and Sink.

This Subject allows sending data, error and done events to the listener.

Broadcast controller, can be listened to multiple times

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you instead of using some transition, use some basic simple code for it. for example you need to define a drawer in your scaffold, and it will handle everything itself.

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      drawer: Container(color: Colors.amber),
      body: const Center(child: Text('body')),
    );
```